# .NET 6 WinForm ClickOnce get open arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, clickonce

I create a can edit ico file application, I publish with ClickOnce.
I want to click ico file to open my winform application, but my application can't get args(file path).

I try: `string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0];`

but ide show error message: `Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivationArguments'`

on my ClickOnceProfile.pubxml file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <FileAssociation Include=".ico">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <Description>ico</Description>
      <Progid>ico</Progid>
      <DefaultIcon>Resources\ico.ico</DefaultIcon>
    </FileAssociation>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

BTY, if I use this code, I can get arg (not use ClickOnce), but I want to use ClickOnce, please help me.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[]? args)
    {
       Application.Run(new Form1(args));
    }
```

```
public Form1(string[]? args)
{
  string filepath = args[0];
}
```

relevant information:
.NET 6
windows 11
windows forms

Comment: That `SetupInformation` property is type `AppDomainSetup` and that class has far fewer members in .NET 6. I've had a quick look and can't see a specific alternative to what you were trying to do, which would have been valid for .NET Framework 4.8. This doesn't help solve your problem but it confirms that you're not going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1:
   Update the VS2022 to the lastest version.
Step-2:
  Project RightClick => Publish => Publish-Tab => Show All => Setting-tab => Options => Allow Url-Paramaters....
Step-3:
  Copy [this file](https://github.com/simmotech/Net6ClickOnce/blob/master/ClickOnceCommandLineTestApp/ClickOnceInfo.cs) code to you app.
Step-4:
  Write Fllowing code:

```
var clickOnceInfo = new ClickOnceInfo();
    if (!clickOnceInfo.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("设计器只能从Web页面启动，无法独立使用");
        return;
    }
    var query = clickOnceInfo.ActivationUri?.Query ?? "QueryEMPTY";
    if (query == "QueryEMPTY")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("参数设置异常,无法启动设计器");
        return;
    }
```